# When I do a git pull origin master from Pantheon, it doesn't seem to pull the database

Tags: database, git, drupal-8, pantheon

I'm new to this workflow using Git, and I feel like I'm missing one piece of information that's just not obvious to me. I setup a sandbox on Pantheon and did a Drupal install thru Pantheon. Works fine on dev. Then I cloned it to my local, but when I open my local up in a browser it wants to install Drupal, like it was never setup on Pantheon. My best guess is that it's not pulling the database, can't find it, and figures it's a fresh install. But how do I connect the dots here? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the database does not pull down with git, only code.

You will either need to manually download the database from their UI or use their command line tool named `Terminus`. If you're comfortable with the command line, Terminus is the most convenient.

Another option would be to use [Kalabox](http://www.kalabox.io/). This is a local dev environment tool which was just released. I haven't tried the latest release yet but have read users reporting it integrates with Pantheon nicely.